# How stream's pipeline works in java like IntPipeline

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm learning about java 8 streams and some questions became to me.

Suppose this code:

```
 new Random().ints().forEach(System.out::println);
```

internally at some point, it calls `IntPipeline`, that I think it's responsible to generate those indefinitely ints. Streams implementation is  hard to understand by looking the java source.

Can you give a brief explanation or give some good/easy-understandable material about how streams are generated and how operation over the pipeline are connected. Example in code above the integers are generate randomly, how this connection is made?

Comment: Take a look at [an answer I gave](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32414480/4125191) to another stream question, which may help you understand the general concept.

Comment: The pipelines are an implementation detail. They can be changed at any time and other libraries can elect to provide their own `Stream` implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Stream implementation is separated to `Spliterator` (which is input-specific code) and pipeline (which is input-independent code). The [`Spliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html) is similar to `Iterator`. The main differences are the following:

- It can split itself to the two parts (the `trySplit` method). For ordered spliterator the parts are prefix and suffix (for example, for array it could be the first half and the last half). For unordered sources (like random numbers) both parts just can generated some of the elements. The resulting parts are able to split further (unless they become too small). This feature is crucial for parallel stream processing.
- It can report its size either exact or estimated. The exact size may be used to preallocate memory for some stream operations like `toArray()` or just to return it to caller (like `count()` in Java-9). The estimated size is used for parallel stream processing to decide when to stop splitting.
- It can report some characteristics like ORDERED, SORTED, DISTINCT, etc.
- It implements internal iteration: instead of two methods `hasNext` and `next` you have single method `tryAdvance` which executes the provided `Consumer` once unless there are no more elements left.

There are also primitive specializations of `Spliterator` interface ([`Spliterator.OfInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.OfInt.html), etc.) which can help you process primitive values like `int`, `long` or `double` efficiently.

Thus to create your own Stream datasource you have to implement `Spliterator`, then call [`StreamSupport.stream(mySpliterator, isParallel)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#stream-java.util.Spliterator-boolean-) to create the `Stream` and `StreamSupport.int/long/doubleStream` for primitive specializations. So actually `Random.ints` calls `StreamSupport.intStream` providing its own spliterator. You don't have to implement all the `Stream` operations by yourself. In general `Stream` interface is implemented only once per stream type in JDK for different sources. There's basic abstract class `AbstractPipeline` and four implementations (`ReferencePipeline` for `Stream`, `IntPipeline` for `IntStream`, `LongPipeline` for `LongStream` and `DoublePipeline` for `DoubleStream`). But you have much more sources (`Collection.stream()`, `Arrays.stream()`, `IntStream.range`, `String.chars()`, `BufferedReader.lines()`, `Files.lines()`, `Random.ints()`, and so on, even more to appear in Java-9). All of these sources are implemented using custom spliterators. Implementing the `Spliterator` is much simpler than implementing the whole stream pipeline (especially taking into account the parallel processing), so such separation makes sense.

If you want to create your own stream source, you may start extending [`AbstractSpliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator.html). In this case you only have to implement `tryAdvance` and call superclass constructor providing the estimated size and some characteristics. The `AbstractSpliterator` provides default splitting behavior by reading a part of your source into array (calling your implemented `tryAdvance` method) and creating array-based spliterator for this prefix. Of course such strategy is not very performant and often affords only limited parallelism, but as a starting point it's ok. Later you can implement `trySplit` by yourself providing better splitting strategy.

Comment: Good answer, thanks. Do you have some material about how pipelines are connected and how stream is made?. I mean, where is the condition to stop creating a stream, and where are the calls to objects' constructor. The source is so abstract.

Comment: @JohnnyWiller, the best material is the JDK source code. Start from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.java#StreamSupport.stream%28java.util.Spliterator%2Cboolean%29) and go deeper. Though I should warn you: this rabbit-hole is really deep!

Comment: hahaha ok :) I will brace myself and look the source, thanks.