# A java 8 stream that maps and collects all except the first item

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a file format for potentially large files where the first line is special. I'd like to open the file once and treat it as a stream of lines, but handle the first line differently from all of the other lines. The others get map/collected, the first line needs to be just parsed into some flags. Is there a way?

This starts as:

```
result = Files.lines(path).map(something).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

except that I want to divert the first line.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34640360/2711488

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you must only open the file once, the easiest thing to do is to make a `BufferedReader`, get the first line and then stream over the rest:

```
BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path);

String firstLine = reader.readLine();

result = reader.lines()
    .map(something)
    .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Note that, unlike `Files.lines()`, the `Stream` returned by `BufferedReader.lines()` does not close the file when `close()` is called on the `Stream`.

Comment: @HankD Right, `reader` should be set up in try-with-resources block.

Comment: Thank you; this rather nice idea eluded me.