# Next line from csv file in Jmeter beanshell script

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I'm trying to make a BeanShell script within JMeter to create an XML message and save it as a variable (and then have a SOAP sampler send the message of course, but that's not really the point). Within the script, I have a loop that randomly creates a few lines, and the point is that every loop the script reads a new line from a CSV file. The loop works fine, but for some reason, the `CSVread next` doesn't seem to work so every time it just uses the same line from the CSV file.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
try{

  //Use a random variable to loop for a random amount of times
  randomnr = vars.get("randomvariable");
  int randomint = Integer.parseInt(randomnr);
  int FiNr = 123456789;

  //I'm using a stringbuilder to create the xml message
  StringBuilder multi =  new StringBuilder();

  for (int i=1; i<randomint; i++){
    multi.append("SomeXML");
    FiNr = ${__CSVRead(data.csv,0)}; //get a line from the csv
    multi.append(""+FiNr);
    multi.append("SomeMoreXML");
    ${__CSVRead(data.csv,next)}; //Go to the next line in the csv - doesn't seem to be working
  }

  vars.put("xmlmessage",multi.toString()); //put all of it in a variable

}
catch(Exception ex){
  log.warn("Something bad happened", ex);
  throw ex;
}
```

Everything is working except that it's not advancing to the next line within the loop. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this function, so I'd prefer not to leave this as an answer, but I would assume that you want `int FiNr = ${__CSVRead(data.csv,0)};` outside of your for loop and `${__CSVRead(data.csv,next)};` should be `FiNr=${__CSVRead(data.csv,next)};`.

Comment: @RowlandB Thanks for pointing that out, it was a rookie programming mistake. Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem with the csv file. I updated the code. Also, `FiNr=${__CSVRead(data.csv,next)};` doesn't work because you need to specify the column for the function to return a value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing a CSV file for a multiple row rows using new Java 8 Streams API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37865492/parsing-a-csv-file-for-a-multiple-row-rows-using-new-java-8-streams-api)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `_csvread()` function will not work with loop inside the Beanshell sampler. Try to implement `jmeter` Loop controller and add `__CSVread()` function under that.