# Java 8 Stream - Filter and foreach method not printing as expected

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am executing the following program:

```
Stream.of("d2", "a2", "b1", "b3", "c")
.filter(s -> {
    System.out.println("filter: " + s);
    return true;
})
.forEach(s -> System.out.println("forEach: " + s));
```

And the output I got is:

```
filter:  d2
forEach: d2
filter:  a2
forEach: a2
filter:  b1
forEach: b1
filter:  b3
forEach: b3
filter:  c
forEach: c
```

However, I was expecting the following output:

```
filter:  d2
filter:  a2
filter:  b1
filter:  b3
filter:  c 
forEach: d2
forEach: a2
forEach: b1
forEach: b3
forEach: c
```

Meaning, first the `filter` method loop should have executed completely and then the `forEach` method loop should have started.

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're doing nothing wrong, this is expected.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414088/java-8-stream-difference-between-limit-and-skip/32414480

Comment: Also your mental model assumes that you would need to go through all the elements of the pipeline before executing the terminal operation. That would be rather inefficient if you need to find the first element that satisfies your predicate for instance.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your expectation is wrong.

When the terminal operation `forEach` is executed, it consumes one element of the `Stream` at a time. Each element it consumes has to pass all the intermediate operations of the `Stream`, which causes `filter` to be executed on the element just prior to `forEach` being executed on same element (assuming the element passes the `filter`).

In other words, `filter` is lazily applied to each element just when the next operation in the `Stream` pipeline requires its next element (in your case the next operation is `forEach`).

This means that if your terminal operation would only require some of the Stream elements to be processed (for example, if you replaced `forEach()` with `findFirst()`), the `filter()` operation would only be executed until the first element passes it (which in your example means the filter will be executed only for the first element).

Answer (score 1):

The processing of a Stream will start with a terminal operation and consume one item after another. The advantages are:

The program has to calculate **only relevant items** - if for example only one item is needed, the `filter` is only called once:

```
Stream.of("d2", "a2", "b1", "b3", "c")
.filter(s -> {
    System.out.println("filter: " + s);
    return true;
})
.findAny()
.ifPresent(s -> System.out.println("forEach: " + s));
```

Output:

```
filter: d2
forEach: d2
```

You can even create **infinte** Streams (which would not be possible otherwise):

```
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i+1)
.filter(s -> {
    System.out.println("filter: " + s);
    return true;
})
.peek(i -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
})
.forEach(s -> System.out.println("forEach: " + s));
```

Output:

```
filter: 0
forEach: 0
filter: 1
forEach: 1
... (up to infinity)
```