# What happens if I'll call limit() after filter() from Stream API?

Tags: java, java-stream

Will the following code filter elements until it find 3 elements that pass the filtering method, or filter all elements?

```
manyItems.stream()
    .filter(it -> it.getValue > 100)
    .limit(3)
    ...
```

Comment: Why not run it and find out?

Comment: Read : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html

Comment: I recommend reading [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32414480/4125191) to understand how this works. Note that your code doesn't have a terminal operation, so it actually does nothing.

Comment: //try for urself       
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
  
        list.add(-2); 
        list.add(0); 
        list.add(2); 
        list.add(4); 
        list.add(6); 
        list.add(8); 
        list.add(10); 
        list.add(12); 
        list.add(14); 
        list.add(16); 
        System.out.println(list.stream().filter(it -> it > 4).limit(3).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        System.out.println(list.stream().filter(it -> it > 4).collect(Collectors.toList()));

Comment: @Optional please refrain from putting code in comments. They are not made for this and your code becomes unreadable.

Comment: Yes @RealSkeptic I understand that. But since it was not really an answer, I thought it other way. I will keep it in mind in future.

Comment: @Optional I don’t think that code in comment is bad, but you should keep it short and simple, e.g. use `List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(-2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16);` instead of a long-winded `ArrayList` initialization. And use backticks to mark the code parts, like in compare `list.stream().filter(it -> it>=2).limit(3).forEach(System.out::println);` with `list.stream().filter(it -> it>=2).forEach(System.out::println);` or even `list.stream().limit(3).filter(it -> it>=2).forEach(System.out::println);`…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`filter()` has lazy execution. This means that it doesn't actually do anything right when you call it. Instead it just returns a new `Stream` that will contain the elements that match the given `Predicate` when traversed.

Since `limit()` is a [short-circuiting stateful intermediate operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps), it will process the `Stream` until it reaches the limit and short circuits. This means that when you call `filter`, it will return a new Stream that contains only the elements, *when traversed*. Since `limit` only traverses enough to reach the given size, `filter` will, in effect, only filter out the required amount of elements.

We can test this by throwing in a call to `peek()`:

```
Arrays.stream(new int[] {1, 2, 2, 2, 2})
      .filter(e->  e > 1)
      .peek(System.out::println)
      .limit(3)
      .average();
```

(Where `average()` could be any terminal operation that doesn't short circuit on its own)

Which outputs:

```
2
2
2
```

(Note that the last two does not appear after the call to `filter()`)

Comment: Small contradiction there: "it will process the *entire* Stream until it reaches the limit and short circuits". If it short circuits, then it won't actually process the *entire* stream. Drop the word "entire".

Answer (score 0):

That method is gonna first apply the filter and then, after that, is gonna call limit on the filtered stream. You can easily try it writing a test.